# Acumatica error after upgrade from version 18.210 to version 18.217 ( Unable to cast object of type ....)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, acumatica

I recently upgraded my acumatica account from version 18.210 to version 18.217, When i try to do an create a sales order.
when i go to sales order tab and try to create sales order i get the  error message

*The  error reads*

Unable to cast object of type 'PX.Data.PXResult`2[PX.Objects.FS.FSServiceOrder,PX.Objects.AR.Customer]'
to type 'PX.Objects.FS.FSServiceOrder'.
[image: Error message on acumatica]

Tace error...

[image: Error on trace]

```
using Autofac;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Data.DependencyInjection;
using PX.LicensePolicy;
using PX.Objects.AP;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.CM.Extensions;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.CT;
using PX.Objects.Extensions.MultiCurrency;
using PX.Objects.Extensions.SalesTax;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.FS.ParallelProcessing;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.IN.Overrides.INDocumentRelease;
using PX.Objects.PO;
using PX.Objects.SO;
using PX.Objects.TX;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Compilation;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.FS;




namespace PX.Objects.FS
{
  public class ServiceOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ServiceOrderEntry>
  {
        #region Event Handlers

    protected void FSServiceOrder_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected InvokeBaseHandler)
    {


      if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
        InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
       FSServiceOrder row = this.Base.ServiceOrderRecords.Current;
            FSServiceOrderExt orderExt = PXCache<FSServiceOrder>.GetExtension<FSServiceOrderExt>(row);            
            if (row != null)
            {                
                foreach (FSAppointment apps in SelectAppointments(row.RefNbr, row.SrvOrdType))
                {
                    if (apps != null)
                    {
                        if (apps.Status == "X" || apps.Status=="Z")
                        {
                            cache.SetValue<FSServiceOrderExt.usrOpenAppointments>(row, false);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cache.SetValue<FSServiceOrderExt.usrOpenAppointments>(row, true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }      
    }



        private IEnumerable SelectAppointments(object refnbr, object ordertype)
        {
          if (refnbr == null) return new FSAppointment[0];
            return PXSelect<FSAppointment, Where< FSAppointment.soRefNbr, Equal<Required<FSAppointment.soRefNbr>>, 
                And<FSAppointment.srvOrdType, Equal<Required<FSAppointment.srvOrdType>>>>>.Select(this.Base, refnbr, ordertype).RowCast<FSAppointment>();
        }

        public string doctype = "SM";
        public string nbr = "";
        public int chkLines = 0;

        protected void FSSODetPart_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected InvokeBaseHandler)
    {
      if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
        InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
            FSSODetPart row = (FSSODetPart)e.Row;
            if(row != null)
            {
                FSSODetExt partsExt = PXCache<FSSODet>.GetExtension<FSSODetExt>(row);

                //disable the SO fields
                PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<FSSODetExt.usrSONumber>(cache, row, false);
                PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<FSSODetExt.usrSOStatus>(cache, row, false);

                //disable action if nothing is selected     
                FSServiceOrder fsServiceORderRow = this.Base.ServiceOrderRecords.Current;
                foreach (FSSODetPart parts in SelectItems(fsServiceORderRow.RefNbr))
                {
                    if (parts != null)
                    {
                        if (partsExt.UsrMarkSO == true)
                        {
                            chkLines++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (chkLines == 0)
                {
                    this.Base.actionsMenu.SetEnabled("createSalesOrder", false);
                }

                //disable chkbox if sonumber exists
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(partsExt.UsrSONumber))
                {
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<FSSODetExt.usrMarkSO>(cache, row, false);
                }                

                //Check the SOStatus
                string strStatus = partsExt.UsrSOStatus;
                if (strStatus == "C")
                {
                    cache.SetValueExt<FSSODetExt.usrSOStatus>(row, "Completed");
                }
                else if (strStatus == "S")
                {
                    cache.SetValueExt<FSSODetExt.usrSOStatus>(row, "Shipping");
                }
                else if (strStatus == "O")
                {
                    cache.SetValueExt<FSSODetExt.usrSOStatus>(row, "Open");
                }
                else if (strStatus == "H")
                {
                    cache.SetValueExt<FSSODetExt.usrSOStatus>(row, "On-Hold");
                }
                else if (strStatus == "P")
                {
                    cache.SetValueExt<FSSODetExt.usrSOStatus>(row, "Pending Approval");
                }
                else if (strStatus == "N")
                {
                    cache.SetValueExt<FSSODetExt.usrSOStatus>(row, "Open-Approved");
                }
                else
                {
                    cache.SetValueExt<FSSODetExt.usrSOStatus>(row, strStatus);
                }
            }

        }



        public override void Initialize()
        {
            this.Base.actionsMenu.AddMenuAction(CreateSalesOrder);
        }

        public PXAction<FSServiceOrder> CreateSalesOrder;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Create Sales Order", Enabled = true, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
        [PXProcessButton]

        public virtual IEnumerable createSalesOrder(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            foreach (FSServiceOrder fso in adapter.Get())
            {
                Customer cust = (Customer)PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<FSServiceOrder.customerID>>>>.Select(this.Base);
                if (cust == null)
                {
                    string exc = "Invalid customer ID";
                    throw new PXException(exc);
                }
                yield return fso;
            }
            SOOrderEntry docgraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
            PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, delegate ()
            {
                Customer customer = (Customer)PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<FSServiceOrder.customerID>>>>.Select(this.Base);
                FSServiceOrder fsServiceORderRow = this.Base.ServiceOrderRecords.Current;
                FSSODetPart rows = this.Base.ServiceOrderDetParts.Current;

                CurrencyInfo info = PXSelect<CurrencyInfo, Where<CurrencyInfo.curyInfoID, Equal<Current<FSServiceOrder.curyInfoID>>>>.Select(this.Base);
                info.CuryInfoID = null;
                bool createso = false;
                foreach (FSSODetPart parts in SelectItems(fsServiceORderRow.RefNbr))
                {
                    if (parts == null)
                    {
                        createso = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        createso = true;
                    }
                }

                if (createso == true)
                {
                    SOOrder doc = new SOOrder();                    
                    doc.OrderType = "SM";
                    doc = docgraph.Document.Insert(doc);
                    doc.OrderDate = fsServiceORderRow.OrderDate;
                    doc.CustomerRefNbr = fsServiceORderRow.RefNbr;
                    doc.CustomerOrderNbr = fsServiceORderRow.CustPORefNbr;
                    nbr = fsServiceORderRow.RefNbr;
                    doc.OrderDesc = fsServiceORderRow.DocDesc;
                    doc.TermsID = customer.TermsID;
                    doc.CustomerID = fsServiceORderRow.CustomerID;
                    doc = docgraph.Document.Update(doc);

                    foreach (FSSODetPart parts in SelectItems(fsServiceORderRow.RefNbr))
                    {
                        if (parts == null) return;
                        SOLine tran = new SOLine();
                        tran = docgraph.Transactions.Insert(tran);
                        if (tran != null)
                        {
                            tran.InventoryID = parts.InventoryID;
                            tran.SubItemID = parts.SubItemID;
                            tran.OrderQty = parts.OrderQty;
                            tran.UOM = parts.UOM;
                            tran.CuryUnitPrice = parts.CuryUnitPrice;
                            tran.TaxCategoryID = parts.TaxCategoryID;
                            tran.SiteID = parts.SiteID;
                            tran.LocationID = parts.LocationID;
                            tran.IsFree = parts.IsFree;
                            tran.ProjectID = parts.ProjectID;
                            tran.TaskID = parts.TaskID;
                            tran.ManualPrice = parts.ManualPrice;
                        }
                        tran = docgraph.Transactions.Update(tran);
                    }
                    docgraph.Save.Press();
                    docgraph.Document.Current = docgraph.Document.Search<SOOrder.orderNbr, SOOrder.orderType>(doc.OrderNbr, doctype);                    
                }
            });
        }

        private IEnumerable SelectItems(object refnbr)
        {
            if (refnbr == null) return new FSSODetPart[0];
            return PXSelect<FSSODetPart, Where2<Where<FSSODetPart.refNbr, Equal<Required<FSSODetPart.refNbr>>,
                                                    And<FSSODetExt.usrMarkSO, Equal<True>>>,
                                                        And<FSSODetExt.usrSONumber, IsNull>>>.Select(this.Base, refnbr).RowCast<FSSODetPart>();
        }

        private IEnumerable UpdateItems(object refnbr)
        {
            if (refnbr == null) return new FSSODetPart[0];
            return PXSelect<FSSODetPart, Where2<Where<FSSODetPart.refNbr, Equal<Required<FSSODetPart.refNbr>>,
                                        And<FSSODetExt.usrMarkSO, Equal<True>>>,
                                            And<FSSODetExt.usrSONumber, IsNull>>>.Select(this.Base, refnbr).RowCast<FSSODetPart>();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Please upload your code *as text*, not as images.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: The error isn't too hard to fix but the images showing partial code don't help. I believe the code throwing that error is not included in the images. Please add relevant information from the traces window (Tools->Trace) and the complete code.